# Improving performance of wildcard date pattern searchs

Tags: sql-server, performance, date, wildcard

I have a wildcard search that I need to improve performance:

```
mycolumn like '%-%%-%'
```

There is a way to do that? (for exemple, with Full-Text Index?)

Obs: I have to find dates in my text that follows the pattern, like 21-07-2016.

**EDIT**

I have a legacy database that I cannot change the structure. So, I have a column that is nvarchar(max). In this column can be stored text and dates. I have to find the rows that dates was inserted.

Comment: what's the data type of the field that you're searching against?

Comment: @RichBenner nvarchar(max)

Comment: My first question would be why aren't you storing these as datetime fields?  Could you supply some examples of the data that you're searching so we can get an idea of exactly what the problem is

Comment: @RichBenner Because I cannot change the database structure. Is a legacy database for a legacy system. In the column currectly can be saved text and dates (as text of course). So, I have to find the rows that was saved dates like text following the patten dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Can you extend the database though? Maybe add a view that parses the fields and have an index on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to change the structure I don't think there is a lot you can do.  If this is a one off I would recommend simply extracting the data out and processing.

If this needs to be a continual/BAU process, the only thing I can think that would improve your performance is to be a bit more specific in your pattern matching to eliminate the false positives you will receive with your current matching pattern.

Assuming your format in the question is the only one you are looking for, you can use:

`like '%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'`